# Arc of Many Hues

Tags: knowledge, visual

What does the below image depict?

[image: many-coloured arc]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks pretty familiar to me:

> [image: an image of Europe, with Spain highlighted in red, France in orange, Germany in yellow, Poland in green, Ukraine in blue, the Black Sea in indigo, and Turkey in violet]

Comment: Apparently I made this too easy! I'll accept the answer in 4 minutes, when the site lets me...

Comment: @matt_rule hey, nothing wrong with an easy puzzle every once in a while. I also happen to be pretty geographically oriented so it probably jumped out at me quicker than the average person

Answer (score 6):

Let's look at this another way...

> [image: The given image, upside down]

Recognise any of these shapes? How about if you look on...

> ...a **map of Europe**?
>
>  Now you can see that we're looking at outlines of Spain (in red), France (orange), Germany (yellow), Poland (green), Ukraine (blue), the Black Sea (indigo), and Turkey (violet).
>
>  [image: Countries used in the rainbow]

Comment: I like your explanation! Now I'm split on which answer to accept. No hard feelings.

Comment: @matt_rule Entirely your choice, according to whatever metric you decide! No worries :)